# Need camera overlay (semitransparent) picture HowTo

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, flash, air

If you know any good starting point to learn how to create such effect using Adobe Flash for an iPhone app, or even an Air app, it'd be of much help.

Specifically, I want it not to save the overlay only show it while the user is taking the image from the camera.

Comment: What options have you explored? What platform is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great link to the camera class that should get you started.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f3fa68e8912e3ab6b8cb-8000.html

You can then add most any objects on top of the video/camera object for the transparent look you are going for.

Comment: no problem.  One thing to remember is that the camera/video object will be the top most item in the display list when it is added so be sure to add any other items that you want to place over it, after you add the video object to the display list - that had me at one point in time.